# Free asp.net async upload control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I'm looking for free asp.net async file upload control (ajax, not flash or silverlight) , which display list of uploaded files. Could anybody help me?

Comment: check my site for your problem solution for dynamically multiple File upload Control
in Vb and C# http://humrahimcs.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/dynamically-create-multiple-file-upload-control-with-asp-net-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [Microsoft's AJAX AsyncFileUpload control](http://ajaxtoolkit.net/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx).

Comment: It can't display list of uploaded files.

Comment: Look at this implementation example, where you will see the image http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/AJAX-File-Upload-in-ASPNET-with-the-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx

Comment: Where is the image? Point me.

Comment: protected void ProcessUpload(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("./") + "image.jpg";
    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(AsyncFileUpload1, AsyncFileUpload1.GetType(), "img",
        "top.document.getElementById('imgUpload').src='image.jpg';", 
        true);
}

Comment: How can this code helps me to display list of uploaded files?